# Unable to login to Azure Mobile Apps(API Services)

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I am trying the new Azure Mobile apps(part of Azure App Services stack), published my mobile service to https://xxxxxxxx-code.azurewebsites.net.

[image]

Previously the application key used to work for password(when I click 'try it out') but now it is not allowing me to. Did anything change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the `MS_ApplicationKey` app setting manually in the preview portal to get it working.

Comment: Thanks that worked. It is really wired, they haven't mentioned anywhere about it in the documentation.

Comment: @trydis Thanks so much man, you solved my problem after all these hours spent trying to figure it out!

Comment: @Chris Great, my pleasure. I was pulling my hair out for a while before figuring it out :)

Comment: Added some more comprehensive instructions on how to fix this through the portal here: https://cmatskas.com/unable-to-login-to-azure-mobile-apps-api-service-formerly-know-as-azure-mobile-service/ Thanks again for the useful tip

Answer (score 2):

Try the Master Key (rather than Application Key). I'll look into whether something has changed, but I just tried the Master Key and that should work.